# SVN commit failed "working copy is not up to date, file system has no item"

Tags: eclipse, svn

I'm using SVN (only for 1 day now) on Eclipse (for Android development) and using Subclipse plugin for SVN

I got an error when trying to commit my project.

The error was that the AndroidManifest.xml file was out-of-date, that the file system had no such item and the file not found "transaction 15-k" and then url to file location of AndroidManifest.xml on the server from the tag that I think was the one I used to restore the project before this error started occurring.

**Couldn't answer my own question, so I'm writing the answer here**

I know now what is happening...

I had restored my project from a tag yesterday.

Then I had renamed this tag in repository... from a0001 to a001

but for some reason, which I do not yet fully understand (but I guess will after I read all about subversion in the manual - but that might take a while).... when I try to commit my working copy, it tries to commit to this restored tag a0001, and not to my main project trunk. And I cannot figure out anyway to edit the destination URL in the dialog after I select "commit".

***p.s. if someone could tell me how I can tell it to submit my project (working copy - files from my computer) again to the main project trunk, that would great. Otherwise probably I will mess up some files in the SVN while experimenting trying to figure out how to do this.***

Comment: Did you run an SVN update before you tried to commit?

Comment: still very new to SVN.. so not entirely sure what an update is... but if it means, did I restore the project from the repository.. I did do that sometime yesterday... not sure if commit problems occurred immediately after that or some time later.

Comment: It's probably worth reading the first few chapters of the [SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/index.html), which explain the SVN model, (updates, commits, conflicts, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, I found the solution to my problems... I found there was an alternative called Git... I installed the Eclipse plugin and I like it more...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest updating AndroidManifest.xml (only that file)... after updating, some conflicts may come out. If that is the case, resolve them and then commmit.

Comment: ok now this new error: update /Users/michael/Development/Android/data/workspace/MyProject/AndroidManifest.xml -r HEAD --force
      C /Users/michael/Development/Android/data/workspace/MyProject/AndroidManifest.xml
    Updated to revision 15.
    ==== Conflict Statistics: =====
    Tree conflicts: 1

Comment: commit -m "" /Users/michael/Development/Android/data/workspace/MyProject/AndroidManifest.xml
    A conflict in the working copy obstructs the current operation
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Aborting commit: '/Users/michael/Development/Android/data/workspace/MyProject/AndroidManifest.xml' remains in conflict

Comment: A tree conflict means you've created / moved / deleted a file or directory which clashes with one someone else has created / moved / deleted in your subversion repository. If you can't figure out how to solve this from Eclipse I'd suggest you get a normal SVN client too and inspect the working copy (making sure to not mix 1.6 and 1.7 clients)